# FacetWP and sorting random listings

Tags: php, wordpress, facetwp

I'm using facetwp, at the moment if I use the facet and just click search without typing anything in the search box, the posts display randomly.

However when I type in a zip/post code and click search its display newest listings first. In the Facet template I'm using

```
'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'rand', );
```

I have tried these few ways but no joy

```
'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'taxonomy' => 'delivery_postcode', 'orderby' => 'rand', );

'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'taxonomies' => 'delivery_postcode', 'orderby' => 'rand', );

'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'taxonomies' => '_delivery_postcode', 'orderby' => 'rand', );
```

Im unsure if I should be looking at the facets template for query's or functions.php